# Working with docker, if app needs redis does VM need redis?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

Yes this seems pretty obvious but I would rather not make an assumption, I do not feel this is information that I could easily google because of the nature of my environment, my environment is mac os x using virtualbox (ubuntu). I am using `docker-machine` and nodeBB.

If I am running a docker app inside a VM then do I need to make sure the required software dependancies for my app is installed within my virtualbox environment?

The reason for ask and why I am confused is I am using nodeBB and I setup a docker container inside a VM then run `docker run --name test --link test-redis:redis -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 4567:4567 -P -t -i nodebb/docker:ubuntu`

The nodeBB setup is actually running the setup which means node is installed I think, but then I get this error `warn: NodeBB Setup Aborted. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` a quick google and I found this https://community.nodebb.org/topic/6337/nodebb-setup-aborted which the theme of this post is redis is out of date or not configured correctly.

So I assume maybe that redis needs to be running on my VM (ubuntu) is this assumption correct or am I missing something?

I am trying to figure out why I am getting this error `warn: NodeBB Setup Aborted. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a redis container running? You don't need to install redis in your VM but you do need to have the redis docker container running as your are linking to it (--link test-redis:redis)

Comment: Cool I am up and running but nothing happens @ localhost:4567? The solution I found was in the NodeBB config it asks for the ip for redis and the default is `127.0.0.1`, instead I put `redis` and it worked, found that somewhere online.

Comment: you need to use the docker-machine IP and not localhost, you can find the ip by using this comman "docker-machine ip default"

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you, no where in my reading was that mentioned, wish it was more clear. Thank you I will note this step for the rest of my docker journey very valuable :)